# Matplotlib fill alpha changes color

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, alpha

I am trying to make matplotlib create a fill that is very transparent by using the alpha command, but it seems to actually change the color. It's there a way to increase transparency without changing the color?

```
ax.fill_between(x, 0, y[0], facecolor='#614126', interpolate=True, alpha=.3)
```

Comment: Is the background white behind the image? If not, it will appear that the color changed.

Comment: If that doesn't fix it, make two axes and have them differ only by the alpha argument. (Could be a color perception thing. Color is weird.)

Comment: Please provide an example (an image would be best) of *how* the color changes

Comment: Indeed ... red that is 50% transparent will appear pink, so we need more info on the color changes you describe.

Answer (score 4):

I've run into a similar issue, where specifying an alpha value caused the color to revert to the default blue. In this case, I was able to override whatever was causing the change by using `setp()`, like so:

```
my_plot = ax.fill_between(x, 0, y[0], interpolate=True, alpha=.3)
matplotlib.pyplot.setp(my_plot, facecolor='#614126')
```